# Default Identity clashes with JWT

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 website that uses Identity for authentication on the actual customer-facing website. It also has an API backend that I want to secure with JWT for external user access.

However, using both authentication systems together is causing a problem. Setting the default authentication schemes to `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` (or empty) causes JWT to fail authentication by routing API calls through the Identity scheme. Likewise, setting the schemes to `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` causes the main site to fail by routing calls through the JWT scheme.

**How can I separate the two so that anything routing through "/api" uses the JWT scheme and all other calls are handled by the default Identity scheme?**

Here's part of the setup so far:
startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => { 

      options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
      options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;

      options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
      options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
      options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
      options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
      options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;

      options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;

      options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                
  }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

...

   services.AddAuthentication(x =>
   {
      // ** Playing with these settings **
      //x.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
      ////x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
      ////x.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
      //x.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      //x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      //x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

  }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
  {                
      x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
      x.SaveToken = true;
      x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(_SecretKey),
          ValidateIssuer = false,
          ValidateAudience = false,
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
      };
      x.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
  });
```

Any ideas would be most welcome. I'd prefer not to have to resort to plaintext Licence keys for the API functions.

Comment: Is that mean your web application has login/out features and user can access some pages after login? And meanwhile the application also has some endpoints start with `/api` which for other applications to call with a valid token?

Comment: @Bemn that is correct. They both use the same underlying services, but use different authentication methods.

Comment: I think I am facing the similar situation too. I am developing a new MVC app w/ user system. On the other hand, I have to provide a set of API endpoints for legacy web apps to connect.  Turns out I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to create an **IdentityServer** application. After that I [added a new client using *client credential*](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) to get the access token.